# Is instantiating a member of class Test within class Test a recursion?

Tags: java, recursion, constructor

Is this recursion?

```
public class Test {
    Test test = new Test();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }
}
```

What about version with [instance initalizer](http://www.programcreek.com/2011/10/java-class-instance-initializers/)?

```
public class Test {
    { Test test = new Test(); }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }
}
```

<sup>I'm asking, because I updated [my old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22182669/what-actually-causes-a-stack-overflow-error/22183286#22183286), which was showing how to make `StackOverflowError` without recursion, but now I'm not 100% sure if codes above are recursion or not.</sup>

Comment: Try it and see if you blow up the stack. Both seem pretty clear to me.

Comment: Did you run the code?

Comment: Your code boils down to the same result. There is no difference. I cannot tell if it's recursive or not, sadly =\

Comment: @DaveNewton `@brso05` OP already knows that this will raise `StackOverflowError`, it's stated at the bottom note on the post.

Comment: I guess you should refer to the formal definition of the term recursion to answer this. I would say yes because the program repeats itself in a similar way.

Comment: @ZouZou I'm trying to do that since few mins ago, but cannot find a good reliable resource that defines a formal definition of recursion.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I think the wikipedia definition is pretty reliable. I.e, you would need to find the base case, and show that all other cases reduce themselves to the base case by following a set of defined rules.

Comment: @brso05 Yes, I did run both codes, they're resulting in `StackOverflowError`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My opinion is that it is recursion. I am not able to find good sources for or against it though. So I have tried to compare the assembly code of a known recursive function with generated assembly code of java code in OP. The two assembly codes are fairly similar, in the question it happens for the  method (Constructor) that calls itself.

My test code:

```
public class Test3 {

  void printMe() {
    printMe();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Test3 test = new Test3();
    test.printMe();
  }

}
```

Print assembly with:
`java -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+PrintAssembly -server -cp . Test3`

Relevant assembly code sequence, showing that the function calls itself:

```
Decoding compiled method 0x00007f2e2910ac90:
Code:
[Entry Point]
[Constants]
  # {method} {0x00007f2e27121230} 'printMe' '()V' in 'com/vs/soutils/Test3'
  #           [sp+0x40]  (sp of caller)
  0x00007f2e2910ae00: mov    0x8(%rsi),%r10d
  0x00007f2e2910ae04: shl    $0x3,%r10
  0x00007f2e2910ae08: cmp    %rax,%r10
  0x00007f2e2910ae0b: jne    0x00007f2e29045b60  ;   {runtime_call}
  0x00007f2e2910ae11: nopw   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
  0x00007f2e2910ae1c: xchg   %ax,%ax
[Verified Entry Point]
  0x00007f2e2910ae20: mov    %eax,-0x14000(%rsp)
  0x00007f2e2910ae27: push   %rbp
  0x00007f2e2910ae28: sub    $0x30,%rsp
  0x00007f2e2910ae2c: mov    $0x7f2e271213f8,%rdi  ;   {metadata(method data for {method} {0x00007f2e27121230} 'printMe' '()V' in 'com/vs/soutils/Test3')}
  0x00007f2e2910ae36: mov    0x64(%rdi),%ebx
  0x00007f2e2910ae39: add    $0x8,%ebx
  0x00007f2e2910ae3c: mov    %ebx,0x64(%rdi)
  0x00007f2e2910ae3f: mov    $0x7f2e27121230,%rdi  ;   {metadata({method} {0x00007f2e27121230} 'printMe' '()V' in 'com/vs/soutils/Test3')}
  0x00007f2e2910ae49: and    $0x1ff8,%ebx
  0x00007f2e2910ae4f: cmp    $0x0,%ebx
  0x00007f2e2910ae52: je     0x00007f2e2910aec0  ;*aload_0
                                                ; - com.vs.soutils.Test3::printMe@0 (line 6)

  0x00007f2e2910ae58: mov    %rsi,%rdi
  0x00007f2e2910ae5b: mov    $0x7f2e271213f8,%rbx  ;   {metadata(method data for {method} {0x00007f2e27121230} 'printMe' '()V' in 'com/vs/soutils/Test3')}
  0x00007f2e2910ae65: addq   $0x1,0xa0(%rbx)
  0x00007f2e2910ae6d: mov    $0x7f2e271213f8,%rdi  ;   {metadata(method data for {method} {0x00007f2e27121230} 'printMe' '()V' in 'com/vs/soutils/Test3')}
  0x00007f2e2910ae77: mov    0x64(%rdi),%ebx
  0x00007f2e2910ae7a: add    $0x8,%ebx
  0x00007f2e2910ae7d: mov    %ebx,0x64(%rdi)
  0x00007f2e2910ae80: mov    $0x7f2e27121230,%rdi  ;   {metadata({method} {0x00007f2e27121230} 'printMe' '()V' in 'com/vs/soutils/Test3')}
  0x00007f2e2910ae8a: and    $0x7ffff8,%ebx
  0x00007f2e2910ae90: cmp    $0x0,%ebx
  0x00007f2e2910ae93: je     0x00007f2e2910aed4
  0x00007f2e2910ae99: mov    %rsi,%rdi
  0x00007f2e2910ae9c: mov    $0x7f2e271213f8,%rbx  ;   {metadata(method data for {method} {0x00007f2e27121230} 'printMe' '()V' in 'com/vs/soutils/Test3')}
  0x00007f2e2910aea6: addq   $0x1,0xa0(%rbx)
  0x00007f2e2910aeae: nop    
  0x00007f2e2910aeaf: callq  0x00007f2e29045d60  ; OopMap{off=180}
                                                ;*invokevirtual printMe
                                                ; - com.vs.soutils.Test3::printMe@1 (line 6)
                                                ; - com.vs.soutils.Test3::printMe@1 (line 6)
                                                ;   {optimized virtual_call}
  0x00007f2e2910aeb4: add    $0x30,%rsp
  0x00007f2e2910aeb8: pop    %rbp
  0x00007f2e2910aeb9: test   %eax,0x16461241(%rip)        # 0x00007f2e3f56c100
                                                ;   {poll_return}
  0x00007f2e2910aebf: retq   
  0x00007f2e2910aec0: mov    %rdi,0x8(%rsp)
  0x00007f2e2910aec5: movq   $0xffffffffffffffff,(%rsp)
  0x00007f2e2910aecd: callq  0x00007f2e290fdde0  ; OopMap{rsi=Oop off=210}
                                                ;*synchronization entry
                                                ; - com.vs.soutils.Test3::printMe@-1 (line 6)
                                                ;   {runtime_call}
  0x00007f2e2910aed2: jmp    0x00007f2e2910ae58
  0x00007f2e2910aed4: mov    %rdi,0x8(%rsp)
  0x00007f2e2910aed9: movq   $0xffffffffffffffff,(%rsp)
  0x00007f2e2910aee1: callq  0x00007f2e290fdde0  ; OopMap{rsi=Oop off=230}
                                                ;*synchronization entry
                                                ; - com.vs.soutils.Test3::printMe@-1 (line 6)
                                                ; - com.vs.soutils.Test3::printMe@1 (line 6)
                                                ;   {runtime_call}
  0x00007f2e2910aee6: jmp    0x00007f2e2910ae99
  0x00007f2e2910aee8: nop    
  0x00007f2e2910aee9: nop    
  0x00007f2e2910aeea: mov    0x288(%r15),%rax
  0x00007f2e2910aef1: mov    $0x0,%r10
  0x00007f2e2910aefb: mov    %r10,0x288(%r15)
  0x00007f2e2910af02: mov    $0x0,%r10
  0x00007f2e2910af0c: mov    %r10,0x290(%r15)
  0x00007f2e2910af13: add    $0x30,%rsp
  0x00007f2e2910af17: pop    %rbp
  0x00007f2e2910af18: jmpq   0x00007f2e2906be20  ;   {runtime_call}
```

Now compare it with the assembly code for original code:

```
 Decoding compiled method 0x00007fea24ef0dd0:
Code:
[Entry Point]
[Constants]
  # {method} {0x00007fea229431b0} '<init>' '()V' in 'com/vs/soutils/Test'
  #           [sp+0x80]  (sp of caller)
  0x00007fea24ef0f60: mov    0x8(%rsi),%r10d
  0x00007fea24ef0f64: shl    $0x3,%r10
  0x00007fea24ef0f68: cmp    %rax,%r10
  0x00007fea24ef0f6b: jne    0x00007fea24e29b60  ;   {runtime_call}
  0x00007fea24ef0f71: nopw   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
  0x00007fea24ef0f7c: xchg   %ax,%ax
[Verified Entry Point]
  0x00007fea24ef0f80: mov    %eax,-0x14000(%rsp)
  0x00007fea24ef0f87: push   %rbp
  0x00007fea24ef0f88: sub    $0x70,%rsp
  0x00007fea24ef0f8c: mov    $0x7fea22943350,%rdx  ;   {metadata(method data for {method} {0x00007fea229431b0} '<init>' '()V' in 'com/vs/soutils/Test')}
  0x00007fea24ef0f96: mov    0x64(%rdx),%edi
  0x00007fea24ef0f99: add    $0x8,%edi
  0x00007fea24ef0f9c: mov    %edi,0x64(%rdx)
  0x00007fea24ef0f9f: mov    $0x7fea229431b0,%rdx  ;   {metadata({method} {0x00007fea229431b0} '<init>' '()V' in 'com/vs/soutils/Test')}
  0x00007fea24ef0fa9: and    $0x1ff8,%edi
  0x00007fea24ef0faf: cmp    $0x0,%edi
  0x00007fea24ef0fb2: je     0x00007fea24ef1172  ;*aload_0
                                                ; - com.vs.soutils.Test::<init>@0 (line 3)

  0x00007fea24ef0fb8: mov    %rsi,%rdx
  0x00007fea24ef0fbb: mov    $0x7fea22943350,%rdi  ;   {metadata(method data for {method} {0x00007fea229431b0} '<init>' '()V' in 'com/vs/soutils/Test')}
  0x00007fea24ef0fc5: addq   $0x1,0x90(%rdi)
  0x00007fea24ef0fcd: mov    $0x7fea226a1f10,%rdx  ;   {metadata(method data for {method} {0x00007fea22543488} '<init>' '()V' in 'java/lang/Object')}
  0x00007fea24ef0fd7: mov    0x64(%rdx),%edi
  0x00007fea24ef0fda: add    $0x8,%edi
  0x00007fea24ef0fdd: mov    %edi,0x64(%rdx)
  0x00007fea24ef0fe0: mov    $0x7fea22543488,%rdx  ;   {metadata({method} {0x00007fea22543488} '<init>' '()V' in 'java/lang/Object')}
  0x00007fea24ef0fea: and    $0x7ffff8,%edi
  0x00007fea24ef0ff0: cmp    $0x0,%edi
  0x00007fea24ef0ff3: je     0x00007fea24ef1189
  0x00007fea24ef0ff9: mov    $0x7c0060028,%rdx  ;   {metadata('com/vs/soutils/Test')}
  0x00007fea24ef1003: mov    %rsi,0x58(%rsp)
  0x00007fea24ef1008: mov    0x60(%r15),%rax
  0x00007fea24ef100c: lea    0x10(%rax),%rdi
  0x00007fea24ef1010: cmp    0x70(%r15),%rdi
  0x00007fea24ef1014: ja     0x00007fea24ef11a0
  0x00007fea24ef101a: mov    %rdi,0x60(%r15)
  0x00007fea24ef101e: mov    0xa8(%rdx),%rcx
  0x00007fea24ef1025: mov    %rcx,(%rax)
  0x00007fea24ef1028: mov    %rdx,%rcx
  0x00007fea24ef102b: shr    $0x3,%rcx
  0x00007fea24ef102f: mov    %ecx,0x8(%rax)
  0x00007fea24ef1032: xor    %rcx,%rcx
  0x00007fea24ef1035: mov    %ecx,0xc(%rax)
  0x00007fea24ef1038: xor    %rcx,%rcx          ;*new  ; - com.vs.soutils.Test::<init>@5 (line 5)

  0x00007fea24ef103b: mov    %rax,%rdx
  0x00007fea24ef103e: mov    $0x7fea22943350,%rsi  ;   {metadata(method data for {method} {0x00007fea229431b0} '<init>' '()V' in 'com/vs/soutils/Test')}
  0x00007fea24ef1048: addq   $0x1,0xa0(%rsi)
  0x00007fea24ef1050: mov    $0x7fea22943350,%rdx  ;   {metadata(method data for {method} {0x00007fea229431b0} '<init>' '()V' in 'com/vs/soutils/Test')}
  0x00007fea24ef105a: mov    0x64(%rdx),%esi
  0x00007fea24ef105d: add    $0x8,%esi
  0x00007fea24ef1060: mov    %esi,0x64(%rdx)
  0x00007fea24ef1063: mov    $0x7fea229431b0,%rdx  ;   {metadata({method} {0x00007fea229431b0} '<init>' '()V' in 'com/vs/soutils/Test')}
  0x00007fea24ef106d: and    $0x7ffff8,%esi
  0x00007fea24ef1073: cmp    $0x0,%esi
  0x00007fea24ef1076: je     0x00007fea24ef11ad
  0x00007fea24ef107c: mov    %rax,%rdx
  0x00007fea24ef107f: mov    $0x7fea22943350,%rsi  ;   {metadata(method data for {method} {0x00007fea229431b0} '<init>' '()V' in 'com/vs/soutils/Test')}
  0x00007fea24ef1089: addq   $0x1,0x90(%rsi)
  0x00007fea24ef1091: mov    $0x7fea226a1f10,%rdx  ;   {metadata(method data for {method} {0x00007fea22543488} '<init>' '()V' in 'java/lang/Object')}
  0x00007fea24ef109b: mov    0x64(%rdx),%esi
  0x00007fea24ef109e: add    $0x8,%esi
  0x00007fea24ef10a1: mov    %esi,0x64(%rdx)
  0x00007fea24ef10a4: mov    $0x7fea22543488,%rdx  ;   {metadata({method} {0x00007fea22543488} '<init>' '()V' in 'java/lang/Object')}
  0x00007fea24ef10ae: and    $0x7ffff8,%esi
  0x00007fea24ef10b4: cmp    $0x0,%esi
  0x00007fea24ef10b7: je     0x00007fea24ef11c4
  0x00007fea24ef10bd: mov    $0x7c0060028,%rdx  ;   {metadata('com/vs/soutils/Test')}
  0x00007fea24ef10c7: mov    %rax,0x50(%rsp)
  0x00007fea24ef10cc: mov    0x60(%r15),%rax
  0x00007fea24ef10d0: lea    0x10(%rax),%rdi
  0x00007fea24ef10d4: cmp    0x70(%r15),%rdi
  0x00007fea24ef10d8: ja     0x00007fea24ef11db
  0x00007fea24ef10de: mov    %rdi,0x60(%r15)
  0x00007fea24ef10e2: mov    0xa8(%rdx),%rcx
  0x00007fea24ef10e9: mov    %rcx,(%rax)
  0x00007fea24ef10ec: mov    %rdx,%rcx
  0x00007fea24ef10ef: shr    $0x3,%rcx
  0x00007fea24ef10f3: mov    %ecx,0x8(%rax)
  0x00007fea24ef10f6: xor    %rcx,%rcx
  0x00007fea24ef10f9: mov    %ecx,0xc(%rax)
  0x00007fea24ef10fc: xor    %rcx,%rcx          ;*new  ; - com.vs.soutils.Test::<init>@5 (line 5)
                                                ; - com.vs.soutils.Test::<init>@9 (line 5)

  0x00007fea24ef10ff: mov    %rax,%rsi
  0x00007fea24ef1102: mov    $0x7fea22943350,%rdi  ;   {metadata(method data for {method} {0x00007fea229431b0} '<init>' '()V' in 'com/vs/soutils/Test')}
  0x00007fea24ef110c: addq   $0x1,0xa0(%rdi)
  0x00007fea24ef1114: mov    %rax,%rsi          ;*invokespecial <init>
                                                ; - com.vs.soutils.Test::<init>@9 (line 5)
                                                ; - com.vs.soutils.Test::<init>@9 (line 5)

  0x00007fea24ef1117: mov    %rax,0x48(%rsp)
  0x00007fea24ef111c: nop    
  0x00007fea24ef111d: nop    
  0x00007fea24ef111e: nop    
  0x00007fea24ef111f: callq  0x00007fea24e29d60  ; OopMap{[72]=Oop [80]=Oop [88]=Oop off=452}
                                                ;*invokespecial <init>
                                                ; - com.vs.soutils.Test::<init>@9 (line 5)
                                                ; - com.vs.soutils.Test::<init>@9 (line 5)
                                                ;   {optimized virtual_call}
  0x00007fea24ef1124: mov    0x48(%rsp),%rsi
  0x00007fea24ef1129: mov    0x50(%rsp),%rax
  0x00007fea24ef112e: mov    %rsi,%r10
  0x00007fea24ef1131: shr    $0x3,%r10
  0x00007fea24ef1135: mov    %r10d,0xc(%rax)
  0x00007fea24ef1139: mov    %rax,%rsi
  0x00007fea24ef113c: shr    $0x9,%rsi
  0x00007fea24ef1140: mov    $0x7fea20c23000,%rdi
  0x00007fea24ef114a: movb   $0x0,(%rsi,%rdi,1)  ;*putfield test
                                                ; - com.vs.soutils.Test::<init>@12 (line 5)
                                                ; - com.vs.soutils.Test::<init>@9 (line 5)

  0x00007fea24ef114e: mov    0x58(%rsp),%rsi
  0x00007fea24ef1153: mov    %rax,%r10
  0x00007fea24ef1156: shr    $0x3,%r10
  0x00007fea24ef115a: mov    %r10d,0xc(%rsi)
  0x00007fea24ef115e: shr    $0x9,%rsi
  0x00007fea24ef1162: movb   $0x0,(%rsi,%rdi,1)  ;*putfield test
                                                ; - com.vs.soutils.Test::<init>@12 (line 5)

  0x00007fea24ef1166: add    $0x70,%rsp
  0x00007fea24ef116a: pop    %rbp
  0x00007fea24ef116b: test   %eax,0x15e21f8f(%rip)        # 0x00007fea3ad13100
                                                ;   {poll_return}
  0x00007fea24ef1171: retq   
  0x00007fea24ef1172: mov    %rdx,0x8(%rsp)
  0x00007fea24ef1177: movq   $0xffffffffffffffff,(%rsp)
  0x00007fea24ef117f: callq  0x00007fea24ee1d20  ; OopMap{rsi=Oop off=548}
                                                ;*synchronization entry
                                                ; - com.vs.soutils.Test::<init>@-1 (line 3)
                                                ;   {runtime_call}
  0x00007fea24ef1184: jmpq   0x00007fea24ef0fb8
  0x00007fea24ef1189: mov    %rdx,0x8(%rsp)
  0x00007fea24ef118e: movq   $0xffffffffffffffff,(%rsp)
  0x00007fea24ef1196: callq  0x00007fea24ee1d20  ; OopMap{rsi=Oop off=571}
                                                ;*synchronization entry
                                                ; - java.lang.Object::<init>@-1 (line 37)
                                                ; - com.vs.soutils.Test::<init>@1 (line 3)
                                                ;   {runtime_call}
  0x00007fea24ef119b: jmpq   0x00007fea24ef0ff9
  0x00007fea24ef11a0: mov    %rdx,%rdx
  0x00007fea24ef11a3: callq  0x00007fea24edda60  ; OopMap{[88]=Oop off=584}
                                                ;*new  ; - com.vs.soutils.Test::<init>@5 (line 5)
                                                ;   {runtime_call}
  0x00007fea24ef11a8: jmpq   0x00007fea24ef103b
  0x00007fea24ef11ad: mov    %rdx,0x8(%rsp)
  0x00007fea24ef11b2: movq   $0xffffffffffffffff,(%rsp)
  0x00007fea24ef11ba: callq  0x00007fea24ee1d20  ; OopMap{[88]=Oop rax=Oop off=607}
                                                ;*synchronization entry
                                                ; - com.vs.soutils.Test::<init>@-1 (line 3)
                                                ; - com.vs.soutils.Test::<init>@9 (line 5)
                                                ;   {runtime_call}
  0x00007fea24ef11bf: jmpq   0x00007fea24ef107c
  0x00007fea24ef11c4: mov    %rdx,0x8(%rsp)
  0x00007fea24ef11c9: movq   $0xffffffffffffffff,(%rsp)
  0x00007fea24ef11d1: callq  0x00007fea24ee1d20  ; OopMap{[88]=Oop rax=Oop off=630}
                                                ;*synchronization entry
                                                ; - java.lang.Object::<init>@-1 (line 37)
                                                ; - com.vs.soutils.Test::<init>@1 (line 3)
                                                ; - com.vs.soutils.Test::<init>@9 (line 5)
                                                ;   {runtime_call}
  0x00007fea24ef11d6: jmpq   0x00007fea24ef10bd
  0x00007fea24ef11db: mov    %rdx,%rdx
  0x00007fea24ef11de: callq  0x00007fea24edda60  ; OopMap{[88]=Oop [80]=Oop off=643}
                                                ;*new  ; - com.vs.soutils.Test::<init>@5 (line 5)
                                                ; - com.vs.soutils.Test::<init>@9 (line 5)
                                                ;   {runtime_call}
  0x00007fea24ef11e3: jmpq   0x00007fea24ef10ff
  0x00007fea24ef11e8: nop    
  0x00007fea24ef11e9: nop    
  0x00007fea24ef11ea: mov    0x288(%r15),%rax
  0x00007fea24ef11f1: mov    $0x0,%r10
  0x00007fea24ef11fb: mov    %r10,0x288(%r15)
  0x00007fea24ef1202: mov    $0x0,%r10
  0x00007fea24ef120c: mov    %r10,0x290(%r15)
  0x00007fea24ef1213: add    $0x70,%rsp
  0x00007fea24ef1217: pop    %rbp
  0x00007fea24ef1218: jmpq   0x00007fea24edcce0  ;   {runtime_call}
  0x00007fea24ef121d: hlt
```

We see the constructor being invoked over and over again. That explains the stack overflow, and appears to be recursive.

Comment: I really like the idea with comparing to known recursive method. I did similar comparison of bytecode generated with `javap -c`. Non-static method recursion involves `invokevirtual` in method body, static method recursion involves `invokestatic` and two cases I presented in a question involve `invokespecial`. They all look alike, the only difference is the `invoke*` instruction, so I agree it is recursion.

Answer (score 0):

This is recursive call as explained below

1. Main method thread executes `new Test();`
2. Before default constructor call of class, instance variable will be
   initialized.
3. Instance variable initializer will again call the default
   constructor.
4. It once again before calling default constructor, it calls instance
   variable initialization.
5. And this is how it repeats the process (go to step 3)

Following example shows instance variable initialization runs before default constructor call.

```
    public class Test {
    private A a = new A();
    public Test() {
        System.out.println("Default constructor called");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }
    class A {
        A() {
            System.out.println("A's Constructor called");
        }
    }
    }
```

output:

> ```
> A's Constructor called
> Default constructor called
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is. You create object in infinite loop and it end up with StackOverflow

Comment: Looping means iteration, not recursion. There is no loop in the code, though.

Answer (score 0):

"Recursion is a basic programming technique you can use in Java, in which a method calls itself to solve some problem. A method that uses this technique is recursive. Many programming problems can be solved only by recursion, and some problems that can be solved by other techniques are better solved by recursion." - [link](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/what-is-recursion-in-java-programming.html)

dictionary.reference.com - "the process of defining a function or calculating a number by the repeated application of an algorithm." - [link](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/recursion)

According to this definition of recursion this is not recursion.  The reason is you don't have a method calling itself in this case the global object is being instantiated automatically since it is in the global scope and that object has an object in its global scope that is instantiated etc...

If you note the definition also mentions "to solve some problem" in this case you aren't solving a problem.

The dictionary.reference.com definition says "repeated application of an algorithm" (ie. method) so it also implies that this is not recursion.

Your case a method is not calling itself a new instance is created each time ie. a new default constructor which is a different method not the same method it belongs to a separate object/instance.

Comment: From the definition in wikipedia: *The power of recursion evidently lies in the possibility of defining an infinite set of objects by a finite statement. In the same manner, an infinite number of computations can be described by a finite recursive program, even if this program contains no explicit repetition* which makes this implementation as valid recursion. But again, it depends on a formal definition of recursion.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza wikipedia is not a reliable source of information. It should not be used for valid sources.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza from dictionary.reference.com the definition of recursion "the process of defining a function or calculating a number by the repeated application of an algorithm."  This implies a method calling itself...ie not recursion.

Comment: This book isn't a reliable source of information either. I don't find a scientific mathematical concept (from which computer science derives).

Comment: dictionary.reference.com is not a reliable source either. With all these, your answer can be considered invalid as well :)

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza actually dictionary.reference.com and books for dummy's are both reliable sources.  And they both back up my answer.

Comment: Seriously, I would trust more in a scientific definition rather than any of these non-scientific.