# Getting inner class to print expected output

Tags: java

Below is a program given for assignment. Request you to help on the below output getting as "Expected output". It providing error as "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError".

```
class A
{
    {
        new B();
    }

    static class B
    {
        {
            new A().new C();
        }
    }

    class C
    {
        {
            System.out.println("Expected output");
        }
    }
}

public class MainClass
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new A();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You call `new A()`, which calls `new B()`, which calls `new A()` again, which calls `new B()` again, and it goes on and on until you can't create new objects anymore (thus [StackOverflowError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22182669/what-actually-causes-a-stack-overflow-error)).

You should stop creating A() or B() at some point

Comment: Please help on the way to stop creating A() or B() at some point

Comment: @UdayaKumar it's unclear (not obvious) what you want to achieve with this program :) Why the need for 3 classes and initialization blocks? Are you sure you know what they do?

Comment: first of all thanks for the prompt response. I am new to java. I was just wondered whether I can get the output from program.  I am just learning.Thanks Cargeh...

Comment: @UdayaKumar: You could achieve that by getting rid of your classes and just putting this one line in the `main()` method: `System.out.println("Expected output");`

Comment: The teacher wants you to get familiar with anonymous black and static block

Answer (score 0):

```
class A
{
    {
        new B();
    }

    static class B
    {
       static {
            new A().new C();
        }
    }

    class C
    {
        {
            System.out.println("Expected output");
        }
    }
}

public class MainClass
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new A();
    }
}
```

> The Anonymous block is executed before any of the constructor
>   static block is executed before loading a static class